# BTRFS new device cannot be added

Tags: raid, btrfs

I have a raid10 setup with btrfs with 5 disk currently:

```
Total devices 5 FS bytes used 6.89TiB
devid    1 size 3.64TiB used 2.83TiB path /dev/sde
devid    2 size 3.64TiB used 2.83TiB path /dev/sdd
devid    3 size 3.64TiB used 2.83TiB path /dev/sdc
devid    4 size 3.64TiB used 2.83TiB path /dev/sdf
devid    5 size 3.64TiB used 2.47TiB path /dev/sdh
```

When I try to add a 6th disk with

```
btrfs device add -f /dev/sdb /backup
```

Nothing happens after I got the message:

```
Performing full device TRIM (3.64TiB) ...
```

Any idea why is that?

Answer (score 3):

After the "btrfs device add", you will have 6 devices. Henceforth, new data will be spread over 6 disks in the RAID10 fashion.

Pre-existing data will continue to be distributed over 5 disks.

If you want pre-existing data to be re-distributed over 6 disks, do a "btrfs balance".